# Simple regex to match a string containing a certain word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match text containing a word (let's say 'word'). I am using the following regex:

```
r = re.compile(r'\bword\b')
```

When I try this regex I get the following results:

```
r.match('a word a') > None
r.match(' word ') > None

r.match('word') > match
```

Shouldn't all three strings match?

Comment: `r.search('... word ...')` would probably work better

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> re.search(pattern, string, flags=0) **Scan through string looking for a
>   location where the regular expression pattern produces a match**, and
>   return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no
>   position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is
>   different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the
>   string.
>
> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0) **If zero or more characters at the
>   beginning of string match the regular expression pattern**, return a
>   corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not
>   match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length
>   match.
>
> Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the
>   beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.
>
> **If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use search() instead**

So, just do r.search(...) and you should get what you want.